# API returning an array of empty objects when request via browser. Same request works fine in postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I fetching data from an api end point. 
When I use postman to send the request, I get an array of of objects (non empty).

[image: postman]

However when I simply request it via the browser I get an array of empty objects...

[image: browser]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass authorization token and Content-Type headers while making a request through the browser.

Comment: When I send the request I get prompted to log in with my user id and pw.. i submit that and I get the response back (with status code 200) , but i'm simply not able to see the data in the browser.. not sure why.. I'm thinking it has something to do with odata?...

Answer (score 0):

Browser only able to make a get request, it doesn't set header value(s) directly for you. You need to add extension of chrome like [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj), which will help you to set request and response header.

Moreover, I don't think you need to worry about it, as I assume you will need application internal call instead.

Comment: I am already logged in.  I am getting back a 200 status code. However the data is not shown in the browser for some reason.. just curious as to why that is the case...

Comment: Logged in to what?

Comment: The browser prompts me to enter my userid and pw

Comment: Logged is something different, it is not relevant to empty data that you're getting. Just change the response format and check